# Can ssh to GCP Private instance but cant access application interface through cloud shell

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ssh, firewall, ssh-tunnel

Here is what i have:

- GCP instance without external IP (on VPC, and NAT), and it accepts HTTP HTTPS requests
- firewall allows ingress TCP for 0.0.0.0 and also for IAP's IP 35.235.240.0/20 on all ports for all instances

I ssh to the instance via IAP and run the application in the terminal on port 5000 and 0.0.0.0 host and leave the terminal hanging, but when I connect in parallel through cloud shell and ssh to this instance through IAP, and then click on web preview on port 5000, I get "Couldn't connect to a server on port 5000".
I have said that it could be a firewall rule blocking IAP, so that's why I gave access to all ports for IAP (for testing)

P.S: the process has been done on a VM with external IP and it got validated ( but without the need to connect to cloud shell to do web preview, I checked the UI with IP:port in the browser )

What did I miss?

Comment: VM is private (Has no public IP address) == not accessible from the internet.
It will only be accessible from within the same VPC. You should expose your VM with an HTTP(S) load balancer.

Comment: I agree, but if you have ssh to your VM through an IAP tunnel (in cloud shell), and then web preview the connection to the right port, why then you can't see the application? you have already the connection..

Comment: Cloud Shell is not related here. the same behavior will be noticed from any other machine outside your VPC.
IAP is a service from Google Cloud that can reach your VM through internal networking to forward only ssh requests. it's not designed to forward other requests, this is the function of LBs. However, IAP can be configured with LBs to detect the identity of who initiated the request and also to protect the LBs access.

in other words, you need to configure the networking to your application (exposing your application to the internet), IAP won't do that for you.

Comment: I am not convinced to be honest, on an old project I used to do the same thing, I used to ssh through IAP to private VMs and then check the web preview functionality on the port of the application and it used to work without any issue, but this new project has other networking configs without doubt.
If you can SSH to an instance, whether by tunnel or else, then why would you not be able to check the app's interface? ( if there are no modified internal configs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be following the guide on [Building Internet Connectivity for private VMs](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-internet-connectivity-for-private-vms) and this part on [Configuring IAP tunnels for interacting with instances](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-internet-connectivity-for-private-vms#configuring_iap_tunnels_for_interacting_with_instances) and the use of [TCP Forwarding in IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tcp-forwarding-overview). By [Tunneling other TCP connections](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#tunneling_other_tcp_connections):

`"The local port tunnels data traffic from the local machine to the remote machine in an HTTPS stream. IAP then receives the data, applies access controls, and forwards the unwrapped data to the remote port."`

You can create an encrypted tunnel to a port of the VM instance by:

```
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel INSTANCE_NAME INSTANCE_PORT \
    --local-host-port=localhost:LOCAL_PORT \
    --zone=ZONE
```

I guess you want to use INSTACE_PORT and LOCAL_PORT the same, **5000**.

Be aware of it's [known limitations](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#known_limitations).